# What happens when we take a compliment in probability and why is sigma algebra needed?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

When we take complement of a set, do we mean sigma algebra minus the set or only the sample space minus the set.

Also why is sigma algebra needed in the axioms of probability ?

For reference the definition is :
Given a sample space $S$ and an associated sigma algebra $B$, a probability function is a function $P$ with domain $B$ that satisfies :

1) $ P(A) \geq 0 $ $ \forall A \in B $

2) $ P(S) = 1 $

3) If $A_1,A_2,\ldots \in B$ are pairwise disjoint, then $P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A_i) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of a set $A$  is also a subset of the sample space $S$, so it is an element of the sigma algebra (because sigma algebras contain the complements of their elements). Symbolically, $A^C=S\setminus A \in B$.

You can't really subtract $B$ from $S$ because $B$ is not a subset of $S$, but rather a collection of subsets of $S$ (and actually $S$ is an element of $B$).  Similarly for $B\setminus A$ with $A \subseteq S$, because $A$ is an element, not a subset, of $B$.

Defining probability as a function on a sigma algebra of $S$ guarantees that you can find the probability of the whole sample space, of the empty set, of the complement of any event, and of countable unions and intersections of  events.

These notes explain the axioms of probability first without and then with a sigma algebra: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/probability-axioms-sigma-algebras.pdf

Comment: Sorry,  I meant sample space minus the *set* (not sigma algebra)

Comment: Oh, then that's right. The complement of the set $A$ is $S\setminus A$.

Answer (score 0):

The $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets of $S$, so yes, if you have some event $A\in B$ then its complement $A^c$ is $S\setminus A$, the sample space minus the event. Note that by definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, if $A\in B$ then $A^c \in B$ so it can be assigned a probability.

Why you need the concept of $\sigma$-algebra? Well, if you have a finite sample space of outcomes $S=(\omega_1, \dots \omega_n)$ then you don't really need anything else than defining the probability of each of its atoms $P(\lbrace \omega_i\rbrace) = p_i$. If you have an uncountably infinite space, say, $S=[0, 1]$ and you are picking random points in that interval, each outcome $\omega$ has $P(\{ \omega \})=0$ so if you would for example ask "what is the probability of picking a number smaller than $0.5$", you cannot assign a probability to this event by simply adding up all the outcomes. In that case we define a collection of subsets of $[0, 1]$ (usually the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) and assign values these sub-intervals of $[0, 1]$.